# how to plot this data?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have an array of values for `theta` and `phi`. How can I easily create a MATLAB plot where `theta` and `phi` are spherical coordinates like this:

[image: hf]

How to plot the values in MATLAB if I have an array of the `theta` and `phi` with radius kept constant?

These are the values of `theta`:

```
theta = [ 80.0000   73.2995   65.7601   95.5007  100.4861   97.8834   94.0849     52.5174 74.4710  104.6674   52.7177   97.0538   75.7018   83.2817   97.5423   85.1797 84.2677  126.2296   81.1814   66.1376   91.6953  167.7085   46.5980   87.8220 113.4588  180.0000   80.7624   95.8623  115.0538   76.5773   61.9858  141.0402  109.9872   76.1273   84.4166   75.2734  110.4489   82.2434   96.8303  100.0815 73.2454   82.0755   64.6457   76.3510   87.7863  133.2706   86.1305   76.8670  86.3225   96.8016   49.2653  107.2900  145.9905   59.2158  107.7546  180.0000 93.9687   87.5474  103.1400  180.0000  136.8251  180.0000  106.2629  109.0069 ];
```

And the values of `phi` are:

```
phi = [ -90.0000  -78.5230  -51.6764   84.6854   58.1182  -75.9705   78.0541  -60.0560  88.8935  -84.6539  -44.1415  -86.7643   61.7764  -87.4767  -86.9440  -80.2459  -76.8752   88.9510   64.7297  -51.1245  -83.1606  -88.7280  -32.7110   81.0951  86.8393   -0.0000   52.6243  -88.7833  -75.4600   84.1374   79.8300  -86.7258  -65.8055   80.9829  -89.3172   57.1802  -80.6346   72.5277  -87.4452   74.2778  -86.1069   76.6124  -80.4604   89.2202   85.0649   89.2164  -79.0290   84.9961  -88.2301  -87.5064   50.4016   83.0830   82.4863  -50.8481   87.0335   -0.0000  88.4613   79.7583  -80.6474   -0.0000   80.0771   -0.0000   89.2428  -82.769 ];
```

The desired plot should be pictorially similar to this:

[image: dim]

I tried using `plot(phi,theta)` and I got this:
[image: hg]

after plotting as suggested by andras
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like googling "matlab plot"?

Comment: wait i will add my results @AndrasDeak

Comment: Good start:) Now try "matlab plot 3d";) You need `plot3`, and you need to convert your polar indices to Cartesian ones: `x=cos(theta).*cos(phi); y=cos(theta).*cos(phi); z=sin(theta); plot3(x,y,z)`.

Comment: Sorry, obviously in my previous comment `y=cos(theta).*sin(phi);`...

Comment: i am not getting any smooth structure @andras deak

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you're using degrees. Trigonometric functions use radians by default. Either convert your angles to radians first, or use `sind`, `cosd` instead of `sin`, `cos`. The former functions expect input angles in degrees.

Comment: the data can't be smoothly constructed on the sphere because if suppose if i get a value (x,y,z) on a sphere and the next value that i get is suppose -x,-y,z then the plot rather following a smooth path on the sphere goes directly to this point as a straight line could it be possible to locate these points on sphere and join these points on the sphere extrapolating from one point to another following  a smooth curve on sphere @andras deak thanks

Comment: It wasn't at all trivial from your question that your points are scattered like this. Interpolating on a sphere from this "random" set of points is difficult and ill-defined, and altogether more complicated than "*how can I plot these (theta,phi) points?*"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108554/discussion-between-boris-and-andras-deak).

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
[X, Y, Z] = sph2cart(theta, phi, P);
plot3(X, Y, Z)
```

Then use [Rotate 3D] button to rotate it to better looking.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
    `[X, Y, Z] = sph2cart(theta, phi, R);`
Which R is the radius of your sphere and here is 
    `R = sqrt(sum(P.^2));`
Then plot it like:
`scatter3(X,Y,Z);`