# how to make a smoothly connected plot on a sphere in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

There are certain points on a unit sphere and i want to join them smoothly along  the sphere smoothly how can i do it in MATLAB,because when i do it using 3dplot function in matlab it simply joins the point using straight lines.

for example there is have a point in first quadrant and the second point in 8th quadrant then it join them using straight line. without following a curved path.

These are the values of `theta`:

```
theta = [ 80.0000   73.2995   65.7601   95.5007  100.4861   97.8834   94.0849     52.5174 74.4710  104.6674   52.7177   97.0538   75.7018   83.2817   97.5423   85.1797 84.2677  126.2296   81.1814   66.1376   91.6953  167.7085   46.5980   87.8220 113.4588  180.0000   80.7624   95.8623  115.0538   76.5773   61.9858  141.0402  109.9872   76.1273   84.4166   75.2734  110.4489   82.2434   96.8303  100.0815 73.2454   82.0755   64.6457   76.3510   87.7863  133.2706   86.1305   76.8670  86.3225   96.8016   49.2653  107.2900  145.9905   59.2158  107.7546  180.0000 93.9687   87.5474  103.1400  180.0000  136.8251  180.0000  106.2629  109.0069 ];
```

And the values of `phi` are:

```
phi = [ -90.0000  -78.5230  -51.6764   84.6854   58.1182  -75.9705   78.0541  -60.0560  88.8935  -84.6539  -44.1415  -86.7643   61.7764  -87.4767  -86.9440  -80.2459  -76.8752   88.9510   64.7297  -51.1245  -83.1606  -88.7280  -32.7110   81.0951  86.8393   -0.0000   52.6243  -88.7833  -75.4600   84.1374   79.8300  -86.7258  -65.8055   80.9829  -89.3172   57.1802  -80.6346   72.5277  -87.4452   74.2778  -86.1069   76.6124  -80.4604   89.2202   85.0649   89.2164  -79.0290   84.9961  -88.2301  -87.5064   50.4016   83.0830   82.4863  -50.8481   87.0335   -0.0000  88.4613   79.7583  -80.6474   -0.0000   80.0771   -0.0000   89.2428  -82.769 ];
```

can these be easily poltted

Comment: How does this differ from [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461846/how-to-plot-this-data)?

Comment: the answers were not appropriate

Comment: @Boris If they were not appropriate, then you maybe update the question to improve it or wait for a better answer. When you update it, it will appear near the top of the queue again and more people will see it. There is no need to create a duplicate question.

Comment: i apologize ,thanks for a good answer @Suever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want MATLAB to plot along the unit sphere like that, you are going to need to specify all of the points in between because MATLAB will only ever connect points with a straight line.

To do this, we can adapt [Roger Stafford's great solution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/277881) on MATLAB central to draw the shortest great circle path between any two consecutive points.

Using the following function we can do just that. We will determine the shortest great circle path between two consecutive points and then interpolate between them to draw the line on the unit circle

```
function plotOnSphere(x,y,z,varargin)

    %// Vectors representing each point
    xyz = [x(:), y(:), z(:)].';  %'

    %// One vector of the "first" points and one of the "next" points
    v1 = xyz(:, 1:end-1);
    v2 = xyz(:, 2:end);

    %// Cross product between the vectors of one point and the next
    cv1v2 = cross(v1, v2);

    %// Compute unit vector in the plane defined by v1 and v2
    v3 = normc(cross(cv1v2, v1));

    %// Figure out the range of the inner angle between v1 and v2
    nc = sqrt(sum(cv1v2.^2, 1));
    t = atan2(nc, dot(v1, v2, 1));

    %// Number of points to sample between any two points on the sphere
    nPoints = 100;

    %// Compute the interpolant
    V = zeros([nPoints, fliplr(size(v1))]);
    for k = 1:numel(t)
        T = linspace(0, t(k), 100);
        V(:,k,:) = (v1(:,k) * cos(T) + v3(:,k) * sin(T)).';    %'
    end

    %// Break the result out into x,y,z parts
    xx = V(:,:,1);
    yy = V(:,:,2);
    zz = V(:,:,3);

    %// Plot the lines
    h = plot3(xx(:), yy(:), zz(:), varargin{:});
    hold on

    %// Plot the original data points
    plot3(x,y,z, 'o', ...
        'Color', get(h, 'Color'), ...
        'Parent', get(h, 'Parent'), varargin{:});
end
```

If we apply the input data that you have provided.

```
theta = [ 80.0000   73.2995   65.7601   95.5007  100.4861   97.8834   94.0849     52.5174 74.4710  104.6674   52.7177   97.0538   75.7018   83.2817   97.5423   85.1797 84.2677  126.2296   81.1814   66.1376   91.6953  167.7085   46.5980   87.8220 113.4588  180.0000   80.7624   95.8623  115.0538   76.5773   61.9858  141.0402  109.9872   76.1273   84.4166   75.2734  110.4489   82.2434   96.8303  100.0815 73.2454   82.0755   64.6457   76.3510   87.7863  133.2706   86.1305   76.8670  86.3225   96.8016   49.2653  107.2900  145.9905   59.2158  107.7546  180.0000 93.9687   87.5474  103.1400  180.0000  136.8251  180.0000  106.2629  109.0069 ];
phi = [ -90.0000  -78.5230  -51.6764   84.6854   58.1182  -75.9705   78.0541  -60.0560  88.8935  -84.6539  -44.1415  -86.7643   61.7764  -87.4767  -86.9440  -80.2459  -76.8752   88.9510   64.7297  -51.1245  -83.1606  -88.7280  -32.7110   81.0951  86.8393   -0.0000   52.6243  -88.7833  -75.4600   84.1374   79.8300  -86.7258  -65.8055   80.9829  -89.3172   57.1802  -80.6346   72.5277  -87.4452   74.2778  -86.1069   76.6124  -80.4604   89.2202   85.0649   89.2164  -79.0290   84.9961  -88.2301  -87.5064   50.4016   83.0830   82.4863  -50.8481   87.0335   -0.0000  88.4613   79.7583  -80.6474   -0.0000   80.0771   -0.0000   89.2428  -82.769 ];

%// Convert to cartesian coordinates
[x,y,z] = sph2cart(deg2rad(theta), deg2rad(phi), 1);

figure;
plotOnSurface(x,y,z);

%// Plot a unit sphere for reference
sphere()
s = findall(gca, 'type', 'surf');
set(s, 'FaceColor', 'k', 'FaceAlpha', 0.01, 'EdgeAlpha', 0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot i have given added above  the values of theta and phi

Comment: @Boris I have given you a function and example, have you tried plotting them yourself?

Comment: @Boris The answer is updated.

Comment: ok ! i am plugging it in my code and test it .

Comment: @Boris Be sure to convert your `theta` and `phi` to radians using `deg2rad`.